# Angular: get logged in user name?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Following [this tutorial,](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local)
I am trying to learn to be able to create a simple back-end authentication with node.js, passport and angular.

I would like to get **logged in user name** with angular but how can I do that?

I am not sure if my question makes sense..so If it is not clear please tell me, I would like to explain it.

I have created a service to get all users..

```
service.factory('Users', ['$http', function($http){
        return {
            get: function(){
                return $http.get('/api/users');
            }
        }
```

and on node

```
function getUsers(res){
    Users.find(function(err, users) {
        if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(users);
    });
};
```

So I can register users on database and I can get them. What I need to compare the users on database with the logged in user so that logged in user can post or read..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show some code

Answer (score 0):

It can be done trough an API that you must build it first if not already exist. Something like `/user/data` endpoint that returns a JSON object about your user credential. This approach is more suitable with SPA (Single Page Application) architecture.

Also it can be done by put a global object in your document that can be accessed by Angular later. Something like (if use EJS)

```
<script>
  <% var globalUser = req.user %>
</script>
```

So Angular able to access `globalUser` variable.

Comment: I have indeed created the /user/data api but is it possible to check logged user without using EJS.?

Comment: Above I gave you option. Using API or template (EJS or whatever). If you using an API, so just call your API like any other AJAX then store your user credential in $rootScope maybe or something depends on your application's architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the tutorial more carefully.

According to it, you should first - create a middleware callback that would handle the authentication:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

Explanation of the middleware:

> isLoggedIn: Using route middleware, we can protect the profile section route. A user has to be logged in to access that route. Using the isLoggedIn function, we will kick a user back to the home page if they try to access `http://localhost:8080/profile` and they are not logged in.

And lastly - use it in the route which you'd like to secure:

```
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('profile.ejs', {
        user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still; how do I pass logged in user name or email to angular controller?